# How globally redirect all https to http with 301 except for certain urls

Tags: .htaccess

We'd like to redirect all https to http with 301 using htaccess mod_rewrite except for certain urls that contain these substrings.

```
/checkout/, /customer/, /cart/
```

There are plenty examples for global redirects. But how can this achieved in combination with some exceptions from the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried it with a url like such (should stay as https), https://shop.de/checkout/shipping.html, but it doesn't.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your `.htaccess` file including the code I provided in my answer?